# For loops to create multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am using an API where I am pulling a lot of data at different time intervals. I would like to create a for loop, that will be pull the respective data and then name it accordingly (where the data and corresponding name of the data are in tuples that are within a list of all the data I am trying to collect). 
I am looking to get a different dataframe for each tuple that is named properly.

I currently have the setup, it is just overwriting the previous data every-time it is ran.

[image: Picture of code and given dataframe. Shows the flow I am trying to achieve.]

Comment: You are overwriting the `name` variable on the line right after the for loop.
Why would you use only one variable in the first place?

Comment: I would like each dataframe to be named, after going through the adjustments outlined in the forloop, the string that is in the second part of each respective tuple. So this code giving me three dataframes named may19oj, mar19oj, and jul19oj.